# Logout user if they break a bashrc command

Tags: ssh, bashrc, google-authenticator

I'm running a small script when a user accesses my Linux host via SSH. This script should verify and/or set up Google Authenticator MFA access for the user.

Right now it works as intended with one caveat - at any moment during the MFA configuration process, if the user (ie) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'s, the setup wizard is interrupted, but the SSH session continues. I need it to log out the user trying to access.

**How can I achieve this?**

This is what I have added at the bottom of my `.bashrc` file (please note that this is **very** new to me and that I'm open to criticism/improvements on my current attempt).

```
# MFA validation/configuration

if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]] ; then
        echo "SSH connection to remote host successful."
        echo "testing if MFA is configured..."

        # is this test enough?
        file="$HOME/.google_authenticator"

        if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
                printf "MFA configured, you may proceed.\n"
        else
                printf "MFA not configured; running setup wizard.\n"

                # the command runs, but the else bit is never reached
                if google-authenticator ; then
                        # I reach this point if I go to the end of the wizard
                        echo "MFA setup successful"
                else
                        # this point is never reached
                        echo "MFA setup failed - logging you out"
                        exit
                fi
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add line

```
trap '' 2
```

at start of you script to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and

```
trap 2
```

in end to enable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> functional.

This will prevent user from brake you script execution.

Note that this should be added to /etc/bashrc, making it system wide and not user-modifiable

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-shell-scripting-disable-controlc/